# How to drag and drop a file from one application to another applicaion in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, drag-and-drop, quickbooks

I have a jquery web application and it contains a list of thumbnail images. The image looks like

> `<a href="#" draggable="true" id="anchorId" data-downloadurl="application/pdf:filename.pdf:http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"><img draggable="false"  alt="" src="imageSrcPath" title="Drag & Drop"></a>`

When I'm trying to drag this anchor tag from my application to my local system (Desktop or any other directory), the PDF file is immediately copied. Its working fine.

But now I want to drag the anchor tag from my application to any other LOB application (Gmail compose or Quick books), nothing happens.

The below code is for dragstart,

```
document.getElementById("anchorId").addEventListener("dragstart",function(evt) {
    document.getElementById("anchorId").setAttribute("href", "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf");
    evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";                             
},false);
```

I'm unaware to transfer the file object in event.dataTransfer to the drop event of LOB application. Because In the LOB application, the drop event expect the file as event.dataTransfer.files.

So please let me know how can we transfer the file on the dragstart event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try :-

```
$(document).on('dragover', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsString(function(url){
        alert(url);
    });
});​
```

get "http://static3.flattr.net/thing/image/9/4/5/5/0/huge.png?1326712342" When I dragged that image from another browser window.

.getAsString takes a callback which gets the url as argument once it's called

Doesn't work on firefox